# How to Query ManyToMany django to find all instances?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I am trying to query to find all instances of `User` that is associated with `self` (a `Venue`). `User` is an extended AbstractBaseUser. This is how I declare stuff:

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    administrators = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), related_name="administrators_set")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         # Get all admins
         # Do stuff with admins

         super(Venue, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have tried using `admins = self.administrators.all()` but get `Unresolved attribute reference 'all' for class 'ManyToManyField'`

Comment: `self.administrators.all()`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem See edit

Comment: But it looks like your `self` is not the object, but the `Venue` *class*.

Comment: nah, print(self) gives the \_\_str\_\_ of the current instance

Answer (score 1):

So the solution that is most commonly known (use of `admins = self.administrators.all()`) is actually correct, however, pycharm does not seem to be able to find the attribute reference `all()` for administrators. It does not affect functionality it seems.

Comment: @RudaMutalik: do you use the Django extension of the (paid) PyCharm IDE? Django uses a bit too much meta-classes, etc. for the (free) IDE to understand it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Even today (June 2021), the paid version of PyCharm isn't capable of detecting this. :(

Comment: @ankush981: well I tried this a few years ago: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/django-support7.html and it was capable to see that `objects` for example was an attribute of the `Model`, even if that was not added through inheritance for example.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Wow, that makes it feel even worse: I have an all-products license and I waste 30+ minutes because my IDE can't do what it can do. -facepalm-